# Snakes and Ladders using tkinter python

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, button, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class Spinner(object):

@staticmethod
def getSpin():
    newSpin = random.randint(1,6)
    return newSpin

class Player(object):

def __init__(self,name):
    self.position = 1
    self.name = name

def setName(self,name):
    self.name = name

def changePosition(self,number):
    self.position = self.position + number

def setPosition(self,pos):
    self.position = pos
    return self.position

def getPosition(self):
    return self.position

def getName(self):
    return self.name

def spin(self):
    newSpin = Spinner.getSpin()
    self.position = self.position + newSpin
    print(str(self.name) + "'s spin was: " + str(newSpin))

class Path(object):
      @staticmethod    
      def buildLadders():
    ladders = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(9)]
    ladders[0][0] = 2
    ladders[0][1] = 9
    ladders[1][0] = 8
    ladders[1][1] = 11
    return ladders

@staticmethod
def buildChutes():
    chutes = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(10)]
    chutes[0][0] = 9
    chutes[0][1] = 3
    chutes[1][0] = 12
    chutes[1][1] = 6
    return chutes

class Check(Player):
    def __init__(self):
    super(Check,self).__init__()

def checkLadders(self):
    ladders = Path.buildLadders()
    for i in range(0,len(ladders),1):
        if self.getPosition() == ladders[i][0]:
            self.position = self.setPosition(ladders[i][1])
            print(str(self.name) + " Landed on a Ladder! from " + \
                  str(ladders[i][0]) +" to " + str(ladders[i][1]))

def newPosition(self):
    return self.position

def checkChutes(self):
    chutes = Path.buildChutes()
    for i in range(0,len(chutes),1):
        if self.getPosition() == chutes[i][0]:
            self.position = self.setPosition(chutes[i][1])
            print(str(self.name) + " Landed on a Chutes!")

class Match_Position(Player):
def __init__(self,name):
    super(Match_Position,self).__init__(name)
    self.match = [[70,235],
                [180,235],
                [290,235],
                [400, 235],
                [400, 140],
                [290, 140],
                [180, 140],
                [70, 140],
                [70, 45],
                [180, 45],
                [290, 45],
                [400, 45]]
    self.name = name
    self.players = Player(self.name)
    self.pos = self.players.getPosition()
    self.position_actual = []
    self.__str__()
    self.actualpos()

def __str__(self):
    for j in range(len(self.match)):
        if self.pos == (j+1):
            self.position_actual.append(self.match[j][0])
            self.position_actual.append(self.match[j][1])

def actualpos(self):
    return self.position_actual

class Display(object):
def __init__(self,master,img,name):
    canvas_width = 650
    canvas_height = 300
    self.name = name
    print(self.name)
    self.pos = Match_Position(self.name).actualpos()
    print(self.pos)
    self.canvas = Canvas(master, width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height, bg = "yellow")
    self.canvas.grid(padx=0, pady=0)
    self.canvas.create_image(300,150,anchor=CENTER, image = img)
    self.animate(master)

def animate(self,master):
    Button(master, text= "ROLL", command=self.say_hello(self.name[0])).grid( row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
    Button(master, text= "ROLL", command=self.say_hello1(self.name[1])).grid( row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

def say_hello(self,name):
    self.name = name
    self.name = Player(self.name)
    self.name.spin()
    Check.checkLadders(self.name)
    Check.checkChutes(self.name)   
    x = self.pos[0]
    y = self.pos[1]
    self.canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+20,y+20, fill='blue')

def say_hello1(self,name):
    self.name = name
    self.name = Player(self.name)
    self.name.spin()
    Check.checkLadders(self.name)
    Check.checkChutes(self.name)   
    x = self.pos[0]
    y = self.pos[1]
    self.canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+20,y+20, fill='red')



class BounceController(object):
def __init__(self):
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Snake and Ladder")
    master.geometry("700x350")
    img = PhotoImage( file = "puzzlor-chutes-and-ladders.gif" )
    name = ['n','s']
    Display(master,img,name).animate(master)
    master.mainloop()

def main():
BounceController()

main()
```

[image]

It printed out this, but the error: 
"'Player' object does not support indexing" pop out.
What is object does not support indexing error is?

And when I click the button, the oval does not actually move.
And using tkinter Button, I can call the method, right?

But by doing so, if I want to make for example, clicking the button, result to the oval moving to different location, how do I achieve that? Since as my code, above, the oval does not move eventhough the button is clicked.

Thanks. Since I'm quite new to python and programming, any help would be such a gratitude.

Comment: Fix your formatting. Indent the *whole* file by 4 spaces before pasting it into this site.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is when you suffix an object with `[n]`, where `n` is an int.  Here is how to reproduce the message.

```
>>> class C: pass

>>> C()[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    C()[1]
TypeError: 'C' object does not support indexing
```

The File entry above the error message tells you the line number and expression that gave the error.  Someplace in your code, as indicated by the traceback you did not show us, you have x[n], where x in an instance of the Player class you defined.

An object is subscriptable if and only if it has a `__getitem__` method, which `Player` does not have and should not have.